# How to adjust the Morris line chart y axis dynamically

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I need to adjuts the y axis in my Morris line chart. The code that I have so far is:

```
Morris.Line({
    element : 'chart_01',
    data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
    xkey: 'fecha',
    ykeys: ['Precio'],
    labels: 'Precio',
    lineWidth: '6px',
    xLabelAngle: 45
});
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image: This is how it looks like now]

And this is how I would like the chart to be, once the y axis is adjusted. Ideally I would not like to start at 0  but closer to the range found. Anyone can help with this? thx.

[image: And this is how I would like the yscale to be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed how to do it:

```
> ymin: 'auto'
```